# PyQt5 - Passed reference is None

Tags: python, python-3.x, window, pyqt5, qwidget

so I'm pretty new to Python. And for the life of me can't figure out why the following code isn't working (I'm using PyQt5). I'm basically trying to have 2 widgets inside a stackedwidget so I can switch between them. And the button to switch from window 0 to window 1 would be in window 0 obviously. So I would need to be able to somehow reference the stackedwidget. But when I try to pass the stackedwidget as a reference, it complains that the variable is None, even when that shouldn't be the case.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QStackedWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication

class DeviceSelectionWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, mainWindow):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
         testB = QPushButton("test",self)
#------------------------------------------------------------
class ModeSelectionWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, mainWindow):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainWindow = mainWindow
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        recordButton = QPushButton("Record tutorial")
        watchButton = QPushButton("Watch tutorial")

        recordButton.setFixedSize(200,100)
        recordButton.setStyleSheet("font-size:30px")
        watchButton.setFixedSize(200,100)
        watchButton.setStyleSheet("font-size:30px")
        recordButton.clicked.connect(self.mainWindow.setCurrentIndex(1))
        #Add horizontal strech layout box (centered)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(recordButton)
        hbox.addWidget(watchButton)


        #Add vertical strech layout box (centered) 
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

#------------------------------------------------------------
class MainWindow(QStackedWidget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(1200,600)
        self.centerWindow()
        self.setWindowTitle("MultiPov Tutorial")

        modeSelectionWindow = ModeSelectionWindow(self)
        deviceSelectionWindow = DeviceSelectionWindow(self)

        self.addWidget(modeSelectionWindow)
        self.addWidget(deviceSelectionWindow)

        self.show()

    def centerWindow(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())



#------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: im guessing that `self.mainWindow.setCurrentIndex(1)` mutates a variable but returns nothing or `None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `connect` method takes a function name, you're doing a function call inside it which return `None`.

```
recordButton.clicked.connect(self.mainWindow.setCurrentIndex(1))
```

One way to get around this is to write a method that does the work (change the index)

```
def setWindow1(self):
    self.mainWindow.setCurrentIndex(1)
```

Then connect that method to the `clicked` signal

```
recordButton.clicked.connect(self.setWindow1)
```

Or, use a [lambda](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/lambda.html) function and get it done in one line

```
recordButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.mainWindow.setCurrentIndex(1))
```

Comment: or use a lambda : `recordButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.mainWindow.setCurrentIndex(1))`